# Render results on submit react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

New to react native. I want to render what is currently being logged in the console into a separate jsx Text elements, but I've been having trouble.

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `http://127.0.0.1:5000/GetRecipes/${searchText}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
      }
    );
    const result = await response.json();
    const recipes = result["recs"];
    for (var meal in recipes) {
      if (recipes.hasOwnProperty(meal)) {
        console.log(recipes[meal].meal); // want to display this
        setSubmitPressed(submitPressed);
      }
    }
    // want to render the results in text elements
    const Test = () => {
      return <Text>hi</Text>;
    };

    const DisplayRecipes = ({ recipes }) => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>Meals</Text>
          {recipes.map((ing) => (
            <View key={ing[meal].meal}>
              <Text>{ing[meal].meal}</Text>
            </View>
          ))}
        </View>
      );
    };
  };
```

The results should only be displayed after a user submits input from a text input field and the results are fetched.

HandleSubmit is called in the onPress prop of a button.

The reference data looks like this
{0, {“meal”: “Chicken Wings”}}, {1, {“meal”: “Hamburger”}}

Comment: Can you share where you have called handleSubmit function?

Comment: can you also share the reference data

Comment: HandleSubmit is called in the onPress prop of a button.

The reference data looks like this 
{0, {“meal”: “Chicken Wings”}, 1, {“meal”: “Hamburger”}}  @NensiKasundra

Comment: Your data should be in array of objects so it will display with map function otherwise it won't be

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {

   const recipes = [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "meal": "ChickenWings"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "meal": "Hamburger"
  }
]

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Meals</Text>
          {recipes.map((ing) => (
            <View key={ing.id}>
              <Text>{ing.meal}</Text>
            </View>
          ))}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

You can set your data as per requirement.